# Fetch() 2 JSONs then() pass to function

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, fetch

I'm trying to plot a graph. The graph function, for obvious reasons, is executed last.

The data sources are from different websites. One's rather fast (`sourcex`) and one's hosted in the middle of nowhere (or so it seems) (`sourcey`).

So `datax` is from `sourcex` and `datay` is from `sourcey`. Both json's need to be returned before they can be run through my script. I have tried the following and multiple variations to no avail.

May I add `datay` is depedant on `datax`.

Please help.

```
var datay;
var datax;

fetch(urlx)
.then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
})
.then(function(myBlob) {
  res=>res.json()
})
.then((out)=>{
  datax=out;
}
.then(fetch(urly)).then(res=>res.json())
.then((out)=>{
 datay=out;
 runThroughScript(datax,datay);
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Comment: You cannot both `.blob()` and `.json()` a response at the same time

Comment: I somehow managed to miss the statement *"May I add datay is depedant on datax."* in the question, and since `datay` *wasn't* dependent on `datax` in the code in the question, I answered as though they were independent. I've fixed the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

> May I add `datay` is depedant on `datax`.

It isn't in the code you've presented, so two answers:

#### If `datay` really is dependent on `datax`

You'd use a chain for it. You have at least two options: Nesting or `Promise.all`.

Nesting:

```
fetch(urlx)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(datax => {
    // Presumably use `datax` here for something
    return fetch(urly)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(datay => {
            runThroughScript(datax, datay);
        });
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Or with `Promise.all`:

```
fetch(urlx)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(datax => {
    // Presumably use `datax` here for something
    return Promise.all([
        datax,
        fetch(urly).then(res => res.json())
    ]);
})
.then(([datax, datay]) => { // Note destructuring
    runThroughScript(datax, datay);
});
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Note that we're passing a non-promise to `Promise.all` as the first array element. That's fine, it'll just be passed through to the result as-is.

#### If `datay` and `datax` are independent as shown in the question

You'd use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for that. You pass it an array of promises, and it will either reject as soon as any of them rejects, or resolve with an array of their resolutions (in order). See comments:

```
Promise.all([
    // The first fetch
    fetch(urlx)
    .then(res => res.json())
    ,
    // The second fetch runs in parallel
    fetch(urly)
    .then(res=>res.json())
])
.then(([datax, datay]) => {     // Note the destructured parameters
    runThroughScript(datax, datay);
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

*(I've removed the blob part that was apparently just an error in the question.)*